# iPad Air Refurbished losing Touch Sensitivity during usage

Tags: ipad

After roughly 1 hour of being switched on, my iPad progressively loses it's gradient of touch-sensitivity.

For example - if I'm using Garageband, the drums gradually lose their velocity sensitivity.

The problem disappears only after a reboot. iPad is new (refurbished).